Package warnings - Not compiling references
Update
The issue was due to having two identical entries in the .bib file with @misc. Once one of these entries was removed, the document compiled successfully with all citations.
I have recently upgraded my PC and reinstalled Sublime Text 4 + Sumatra PDF for LaTeX.
I am encountering an issue where I can compile LaTeX documents that do not involve citations. However, when compiling LaTeX documents, such as academic papers, that include citations using \cite{}, the compilation is only partial. The citations are not included, and a ‘?’ is displayed instead. Making a minor change to the document, such as adding a word to the body, and then recompile, no changes are reflected.
I have implemented an small version (see files below) that successfully compiles the document and generates the corresponding citations. However, as I continue to add citations, LaTeX eventually crashes and displays all citations as ‘?’, particularly when citing keys with @misc.
Main file
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{setspace} %[onehalfspacing] 
\usepackage{parboxx} % Need for tables
\usepackage{tabularx} % extra features for tabular environment
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage{epstopdf} %eps files
\usepackage[margin=1in,a4paper]{geometry} % decreases margins
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} % adds hyper links inside the generated pdf file
\usepackage{color,soul} % for highlighting 
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.15cm}  % for space between paragraphs
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % for space between lines
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{eurosym} % To be able to write down the euro symbol
\usepackage{graphicx,rotating,booktabs} % Horizontal tables
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[verbose]{placeins}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} %Appendix


\usepackage{natbib}             %Bibliography cite 
\bibliographystyle{aer}


\usepackage{array}  % I don't know how come I didn't have this.
\usepackage{arydshln} % To create dashed lines in my tables.
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} % Two figures side by side.
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Makes sure the footnotes appear at the end of the page, and not right below the text, which annoys the sh#t out of me.
\usepackage{makecell} % To break the lines inside of a cell.
\usepackage{bbm} % Indicator function
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes} % To do notes
\usepackage{comment} %To do comments
\usepackage{bm} % Allow for width adjustment.
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.} %Sections with roman numbers (\Alph, \arabic, \roman, and \Roman)
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\Alph{subsection}.} %Subsections Letters
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}% Tables roman numbers
%\captionsetup[table]{name=TABLE}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\usepackage{titling} %title and subtiles
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\LARGE#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\usepackage{lscape} %landscape mode
\usepackage{abstract,lipsum} % abstract
\usepackage{authblk} % more than one author

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\newenvironment{question}
    {\begin{singlespacing} \bfseries \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}}
    {\end{adjustwidth} \end{singlespacing}}  % Adjust width environment.

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,     % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue         
}

% Define command used when I am adding stuff
%\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses headers and footers on the title page

    \centering % Centre everything on the title page
    
    \scshape % Use small caps for all text on the title page
    
    \vspace*{\baselineskip} % White space at the top of the page
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------
    
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal rule
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} % Thin horizontal rule
    
    {\LARGE Title \footnote[1]{ bla bla}}
    %\vspace{0.75\baselineskip} % Whitespace below the title
    
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal rule
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt} % Thick horizontal rule
    
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Subtitle
    %------------------------------------------------
    
    \vspace*{1\baselineskip} % Whitespace under the subtitle
    
    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Editor(s)
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip} % Whitespace before the editors

    {\scshape\Large Author}\footnote[2]{I am very grateful to bla bla bla.} 
    
    \vspace{0\baselineskip} 
    
 {\small{First draft 10.04.2022 \\ Current version 10.11.2023}}

\begin{abstract}
This paper analyses bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\end{abstract}  

\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{JEL classification}: 895. \\
\textbf{Keywords}: Key1, key2. key3.
\end{flushleft}
    \vfill 
\end{titlepage}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\newpage
{\centering \section{\scshape Introduction}}
hello 
\cite{ciccarelli2021expectation} , \cite{martinez2010global},\cite{kabukccuouglu2018inflation},\cite{duncan2023forecasting}
\newpage{}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}

File .bib with all keys
% Encoding: UTF-8
@article{ciccarelli2021expectation,
  title={Expectation spillovers and the return of inflation},
  author={Ciccarelli, Matteo and Garc{\'\i}a, Juan Angel},
  journal={Economics Letters},
  volume={209},
  pages={110119},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@book{martinez2010global,
  title={The global slack hypothesis},
  author={Mart{\'\i}nez-Garc{\'\i}a, E and Wynne, MA},
  number={10},
  year={2010},
  publisher={DIANE Publishing}
}
@article{kabukccuouglu2018inflation,
  title={Inflation as a global phenomenon—Some implications for inflation modeling and forecasting},
  author={Kabuk{\c{c}}uo{\u{g}}lu, Ay{\c{s}}e and Mart{\'\i}nez-Garc{\'\i}a, Enrique},
  journal={Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control},
  volume={87},
  pages={46--73},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{duncan2023forecasting,
author = {Duncan, Roberto and Martínez-García, Enrique},
title = {Forecasting inflation in open economies: What can a NOEM model do?},
journal = {Journal of Forecasting},
volume = {42},
number = {3},
pages = {481-513},
keywords = {inflation forecasting, New Open Economy Macro model, open-economy Phillips curves},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1002/for.2941},
url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/for.2941},
eprint = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/for.2941},
abstract = {Abstract This paper evaluates the forecasting ability when inflation is viewed as an inherently global phenomenon through the lens of the workhorse New Open Economy Macro (NOEM) model. The NOEM model emphasizes the importance of cross-country spillovers arising through trade, and its reduced form solution can be represented by a finite-order VAR that provides a tractable model of inflation forecasting. We use Bayesian techniques to estimate this VAR specification—we name it NOEM-BVAR—and pseudo-out-of-sample forecasts to assess its forecasting performance at different horizons in a diverse set of 18 countries. On average, the NOEM-BVAR specification produces a similar or even lower root mean square prediction error (RMSPE) than its standard competitors, which include both purely statistical models and theoretically-based forecasting models (e.g., Phillips-curve-type alternatives and others with global inflation measures). In a number of cases, the gains in smaller RMSPEs are statistically significant, especially at short horizons. The NOEM-BVAR model is also accurate in predicting the direction of change for inflation and is often better than its competitors along this dimension as well. Even though purely statistical models can be useful as prediction tools, the NOEM-BVAR is an attractive tool among those forecasting models motivated by economic theory.},
year = {2023}
}
@article{stephens2000dealing,
  title={Dealing with label switching in mixture models},
  author={Stephens, Matthew},
  journal={Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology)},
  volume={62},
  number={4},
  pages={795--809},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{geweke2007interpretation,
  title={Interpretation and inference in mixture models: Simple MCMC works},
  author={Geweke, John},
  journal={Computational Statistics \& Data Analysis},
  volume={51},
  number={7},
  pages={3529--3550},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{morley2003beveridge,
  title={Why are the Beveridge-Nelson and unobserved-components decompositions of GDP so different?},
  author={Morley, James C and Nelson, Charles R and Zivot, Eric},
  journal={Review of Economics and Statistics},
  volume={85},
  number={2},
  pages={235--243},
  year={2003},
  publisher={MIT Press 238 Main St., Suite 500, Cambridge, MA 02142-1046, USA journals~…}
}
@article{primiceri2005time,
  title={Time varying structural vector autoregressions and monetary policy},
  author={Primiceri, Giorgio E},
  journal={The Review of Economic Studies},
  volume={72},
  number={3},
  pages={821--852},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Wiley-Blackwell}
}
@article{stock2007has,
  title={Why has US inflation become harder to forecast?},
  author={Stock, James H and Watson, Mark W},
  journal={Journal of Money, Credit and banking},
  volume={39},
  pages={3--33},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{stock1988variable,
  title={Variable trends in economic time series},
  author={Stock, James H and Watson, Mark W},
  journal={Journal of economic perspectives},
  volume={2},
  number={3},
  pages={147--174},
  year={1988},
  publisher={American Economic Association}
}

Output:
[Compiling C:\...\Desktop\Prueba Latex\Prueba2.tex]

TraditionalBuilder: Engine: lualatex. Invoking texify... done.

No errors. Warnings:

C:\...\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls:140: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmr/bx/sc' undefined(Font)              using `TU/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 140.
C:\...\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls: LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

C:\...\Desktop\Prueba Latex\Prueba2.log:1: Double-click here to open the full log.

[Done!]


getting ? on the first run is expected, then you need to run bibtex to generate the bibliography then run pdflatex twice more.

unrelated to bibliography but you are using luatex or xetex so remove \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} the first does nothing as shown in the message you quote above, the second will break the unicode support and with xetex cause incorrect hyphenation and linebreaking

welcome! sublime-text is irrelevant here: it is just your editor. the reason it works on overleaf is that overleaf does all this automatically for you i.e. compiles, runs bibtex, compiles and compiles again. you can use a tool such as latexmk or arara to automate compilation locally, if you wish.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comments. I believe my issue differs from the question you have suggested, as my .bbl file is not empty and I have a .blg file. I must mention that I am a novice with LaTeX. Several years ago, a friend installed Sublime Text 3 for me, and since then, I have only needed to compile by pressing Ctrl + B, with Sublime Text and Sumatra PDF handling the rest. I have never manually run BibTeX followed by PDFLaTeX.

@cfr Thank you for your comment. I do have latexmk installed in MikTeX.

well if you have a bbl file you have run bibtex so have you run latex twice after running bibtex, the log ytou posted shows Rerun to get cross-references right. have you done that?

your .bbl doesn't contain an item for the key ciccarelli2021expectation which latex is complaining is undefined. do you have an entry in your .bib file with this key?

@cfr, thank you for your comment. The "ciccarelli2021expectation" key is already in the .bib file, and I have now reedited the post to include my .bib file. So you can see the content of this file.

@DavidCarlisle, thank you for your comment. The document does contain cross-references that function correctly, such as those referring to sections. For example: \section{Introduction} \label{ref_intro} \ref{ref_intro}. I am not sure whether you are refering to this.

Can you please try to reduce your preamble and at the same time extend your code to a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)? Currently we need a combination of guessing what is needed to reproduce your issue and clean your code from not needed parts. A MWEB would help us to help you.

The question is have you re-run latex until you have no message in the log saying to run it again.  It is quite normal for the bibliography to be incomplete in initial runs.

you also need to re-run bibtex by the look of your fragments (you always need to re-run bibtex if you add a new \cite)

@cabohah, I have implemented an MWEB as per your suggestion and will share it shortly. It appears to successfully compile the document and generate the corresponding citations. However, as I continue to add citations, LaTeX eventually crashes and displays all citations as ‘?’.

it isn't an MWEB if it doesn't reproduce the problem ;). start from your real document, make a copy and remove stuff. if the problem goes away, put back the last thing you took out.

you have \harvarditem in your .bbl. natbib defines that, but it will only be used if you use an appropriate style, so what does your \bibliographystyle{} line look like?

if you need further help, could you please format your code blocks so people don't need to edit every time you update? you can do this by highlighting the code and clicking the {} button or pressing ctrl-k. or you can put three back ticks on a line by themselves before the code and another three on a line by themselves after.
